# Convert Delphi ClientDataSet to dfXML

Tags: xml, delphi, data-structures, tclientdataset

I've just installed Delphi 7 for Personal Use and I'm trying to convert a delphi ClientDataSet file to dfXMLUTF8. All I really need is the xml structure.  [This site](http://embarcadero.newsgroups.archived.at/public.delphi.language.delphi.win32/200809/080930704.html) suggests that running 4 lines of code will generate the output I desire. Note however that My file is .cds, not .dat as in the example. I don't know if this makes a difference.

```
ClientDataSet1.Active := false;
ClientDataSet1.CreateDataSet;
ClientDataSet1.LoadFromFile('MyBinaryFile.dat');
ClientDataSet1.SaveToFile('MyXMLFile.XML', dfXMLUTF8);
```

I'm receiving errors and since I've never really used Delphi before and I'm hoping somebody who knows what they are doing could just post the *very short* xml structure for me. [Here's the file(486 bytes)](https://rapidshare.com/files/2116612914/Structure.cds) I'm working with. I will award correct answer to the first poster with full dfXMLUTF8 output. Thanks!

**Update**:

Okay I just started the project from scratch and I think I have it somewhat setup. I have added `uses DBClient;`, `var ClientDataSet1: TClientDataSet`, and lastly the procedure:

```
ClientDataSet1.LoadFromFile('C:\Documents and Settings\XPMUser\Desktop\DelphiCDS\Master.cds');
  ClientDataSet1.SaveToFile('C:\Documents and Settings\XPMUser\Desktop\DelphiCDS\output.XML', dfXMLUTF8);
```

It throws the following error:

> Access violation at address 004588B6 in module 'Project.exe'. Read of
>   address 00000000.

**Update2**:

Here's what I ended up with:

```
unit Script3;

interface

uses
  Forms, DBClient;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;
  CDS: TClientDataSet;

implementation
{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  CDS := TClientDataSet.Create(nil);
  try
    CDS.LoadFromFile('.\input.cds');
    CDS.SaveToFile('.\output.xml', dfXMLUTF8);
  finally
    CDS.Free;
  end;
end;

end.
```

Comment: When you say "I'm receiving errors", it's extremely useful if you actually provide **the errors** in your question text, since we can't see your screen from where we are. Please edit your question and provide the **exact** error message you're getting. Thanks.

Comment: I gave you **specific code** about how to create and use a `TClientDataSet` in code in my answer below. If you're getting that access violation, you're not using the code I posted. Please read again; you apparently missed the `CDS := TClientDataSet.Create(nil)` and `CDS.Free;` parts of it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're doing much more than you have to in order to accomplish the conversion. With the presumption that `MyBinaryFile.dat` is actually a binary format Delphi `TClientDataSet` file, these two lines of code (with no additional setup) will work:

```
ClientDataSet1.LoadFromFile('D:\Temp\MyBinaryFile.dat');
ClientDataSet1.SaveToFile('D:\Temp\MyXMLFile.xml', dfXMLUTF8);
```

Without knowing more about what your `MyBinaryFile.dat` is, and no information about the errors you're getting, it's pretty difficult to provide more information. Tested and working with the standard `animals.cds` in Delphi 7 (from `C:\Program Files\Common Files\Borland Shared\Data` in a standard D7 install on a Windowx XP virtual machine).

It seems, from your comment below, that the actual problem you're having is a compiler error about an unidentified identifier `TClientDataSet` when you try and create it in code. If you have a high enough SKU for Delphi 7 that includes `TClientDataSet` (IIRC, Professional and higher), you can just add `DBClient` to your uses clause:

```
implementation

uses 
  DBClient;

procedure TForm1.FormShow(Sender: TObject);
var
  CDS: TClientDataSet;
begin
  CDS := TClientDataSet.Create(nil);
  try
    CDS.LoadFromFile('MyBinaryFile.dat');
    CDS.SaveToFile('MyXMLFile.xml', dfXMLUTF8);
  finally
    CDS.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Or, better yet, if you're creating a VCL Forms application, just drop a `TClientDataSet` on your form; you'll find it on the `DataAccess` tab in the component palette.

Comment: I'm an absolute beginner. I'm declaring [code]var ClientDataSet1: TClientDataSet;[/code] and receiving undeclared identifier TClientDataSet.

Comment: My actual CDS file is linked on my opening question. I just don't know a single thing about Delphi. What variable type should CLientDataSet1 be?

Comment: If TClientDataSet is available in the edition of Delphi 7 you're using (Professional and higher SKUs, IIRC), just add `DBClient` to your uses clause. (Or drop a `TClientDataSet` on your form from the `DBAccess` tab in the component palette.) If you'd mentioned that in your original question, I could have addressed that in my answer as well.

Comment: Alright I think I added that correctly. How do I run this script? "Run" is grayed out.

Comment: Updated the OP with my latest.

Comment: Delphi isn't a scripting language. It's a compiled programming language that creates native Win32 executable files. You need to put the code in a project (File|New|VCL Forms Application or File|New|Other|Console Application), and then compile and run that project. StackOverflow isn't a programming tutorial site. You need to find a site that teaches the basics. Try [Delphi About](http://delphi.about.com) or [Marco Cantu's site](http://marcocantu.com).